# tutorial reactjs : Optimisation

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering why on the facebook's react JS tutorial (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#optimization-optimistic-updates) we don't just add `this.loadCommentsFromServer();` after the ajax query in `handleCommentSubmit`?

Thanks

What I want to do :

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

What FB do :

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var comments = this.state.data;
    // Optimistically set an id on the new comment. It will be replaced by an
    // id generated by the server. In a production application you would likely
    // not use Date.now() for this and would have a more robust system in place.
    comment.id = Date.now();
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({data: comments});
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you could post a larger chunk of the relevant code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code for the server they provide, the `POST` [returns the new comments after updating](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/blob/master/server.js#L48-72).

You can assume this by looking at the tutorial you've specified, since the response seems to be put back into state as following:
`success: function(data) { this.setState({data: data}); }`

Comment: So if the state is updated with the POST's response, why would we need the optimisation described in the tutorial ?
When I remove my optimisation, the comments are updated instantly ... It was not before my optimisation.

Comment: The new comment is added to the list even before the `POST`, so it will show up on the list instantly. Without it, you'll have to wait for the `POST` to complete and return the data for it to show up in the list. This is why it's labeled as optimistic update.